# How to implement repository without storing query results in memory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

**Scenario**

I need to read over 5 million items from database and process them one by one without having to store all of the collection in memory. Let me write an oversimplified C# inspired pseudocode to clarify (please note that the question is about the usages of LINQ, group by and count etc) -

```
Lets say the table has the following fields - Id, Name, Age

IList<string> resultList = ...
IDataReader reader = command.executereader...
while(reader.Read()) //Read only one item at a time, no need to load everything
    if (AggregateFunction(resultList, reader.Name, reader.Age))
        resultList.Add(reader.Name);
```

**Problem**
If I use an IDataReader, I don't have to store all of the 5 million items in memory. I can just loop over them and my memory requirement is just one row at a time.

But if I use Repository pattern with IEnumerable etc, then I will be forced to store all of the 5 million items in memory before I can process them. The code would look like -

```
IEnumerable<...> tableData = repository.GetAll() // Here we loaded everything in the memory
foreach(var row in tableData)
    //Do whatever...
```

Should I skip Repository pattern and just do this the old fashioned way? Or is there a way to get the benefits of Respository pattern without loading everything in memory?

Note: The solution that comes to my mind is creating a
        repository.GetAggregatedResult(Func aggregateFunction)
 but that doesn't feel cleaner. Plus, the real problem here is - **how to iterate on repository one item at a time without storing the whole result set in memory**

Comment: You can always write your repository to accept parameters and select only specific rows or specific number of rows.

Comment: Right. But we do want to read all of the rows. It's just that we want to process each row as soon as it is read and then discard instead of storing in the memory.

Comment: You can't expect to have a list of rows and not store them in memory, because if you have a list of _something_, it's in memory.  You have to intelligently load them, process them and then load some more.  What's wrong with establishing a connection and then using that same connection to request more rows?

Comment: So, you're saying that IDataReader.Read() is same as loading the complete resultset in the memory? I can read them in batches but then for 5 million rows, we're talking about firing hundreds of thousands of queries.

Comment: Reading them in batches is one solution but then for 5 million rows it's going to be too many queries going to the database. Plus it is not really clean (more of a hack to force the Repository pattern to work imho), it requires some plumbing on both Repository and consumer's end. Is there a way to do some sort of one row at a time lazy load with IRepository? Or perhaps Repository pattern is simply not a good pattern for this scenario? I don't know.

Comment: if you need to do processing on huge data then why not doing it on database side? and then send the output to application

Comment: Because the algorithms doing the processing are implemented in an external library (.NET dll).

Comment: I want to remain open minded here, I know what you want but I'm not sure it's possible... do databases return records one at a time like that?  You want a single query and for the records to be returned one by one for processing.  When you say it's too many queries, if a database engine does return a record one by one, isn't it doing the same amount of processing behind the scenes as if it were receiving and processing multiple queries?

Comment: I understand, your solution is good. But I'm also wondering if creating query plans and whatever other overheads the db will have after introducing extra where conditions will make it much inefficient for such a huge resultset (one select * from T vs many select only n * from T where x between a and b).

Comment: But also, this should be a common enough problem in most projects out there that deal with huge datasets. I keep wondering if there's some pattern to deal with such scenarios. Maybe I'm overengineering, what if I keep the query and everything in the repository but return the IDataReader to the client/helper class will it break repository pattern? By either exposing IDataReader or doing yield return, the database is still abstracted away, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you can't implement a method like this:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
     IEnumerable<string> GetFilteredNames(Func<Person, bool> predicate);
}
```

Also, a domain object like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte Age { get; set; } 
    // byte should be fine unless you would be 
    // working with turtles instead of persons ;)
}
```

...and implement it using a raw `IDataReader` implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFilteredNames(Func<Person, bool> predicate)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    IDataReader dataReader = ... // Who knows how you get it!

    while(dataReader.Read()) 
    {
        Person person = new Person 
        {
            Id = (int)dataReader["Id"],
            Name = (string)dataReader["Name"],
            Age = (byte)dataReader["Age"]
        };

        if(predicate(person))
           result.Add(person.Name);
    }

    return result;    
}
```

If you want to make it absolutely agnostic, you may be able to use dependency injection on repository to inject a `IDataReader` factory!

Now you can continue with the world of wonders of repository pattern:

```
var result = repoImpl.GetFilteredNames(person => AggregateFunction(person.Id, person.Name, person.Age));
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach best so far. I'm very inclined to use it, yet I've been avoiding it mainly because the "if(predicate(person)) result.Add(person.Name);" part feels like a bit of business logic to me (even though I realize that it is effectively similar to a where clause). Could you please elaborate on what you mean by injecting an IDataReader factory as well? Did you mean - expose the IDataReader to the business layer?

Comment: @Achilles Don't be perfectionist ;) Now any logic will instantly be *domain* (ironic mode off). A repository acts like an in-memory collection and it's the barrier between the domain and the data mapper layer. No one says you can't use an `if` or even more complex logic within a repository method. It's ok filtering objects within the repository if other layer wouldn't be able to do so efficiently.

Comment: @Achilles About the factory, I mean using dependency injection and an inversion of control container like Castle Windsor to inject the `IDataReader` implementation instead of manually opening there a connection and a reader. This will increase your repo testability.